# Extracting some HTML tag values in Python

Tags: python, html, regex, parsing

How to get a value of nested `<b>` HTML tag in Python using regular expressions?

```
<a href="/model.xml?hid=90971&amp;modelid=4636873&amp;show-uid=678650012772883921" class="b-offers__name"><b>LG</b> X110</a>

# => LG X110
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question was very hard to understand, but from the given output example it looks like you want to strip everything within `<` and `>` from the input text. That can be done like so:

```
import re
input_text = '<a bob>i <b>c</b></a>'
output_text = re.sub('<[^>]*>', '', input_text)
print output_text
```

Which gives you:

```
i c
```

If that is not what you want, please clarify.

Please note that the regular expression approach for parsing XML is very brittle.  For instance, the above example would break on the input `<a name="b>c">hey</a>`.  (`>` is a valid character in a attribute value: [see XML specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-AttValue))

Answer (score 7):

You don't.

Regular Expressions are not well suited to deal with the nested structure of HTML. Use an [HTML parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) instead.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use regular expressions for parsing HTML. Use an HTML parser like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). Just look how easy it is:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
html = r'<a href="removed because it was too long"><b>LG</b> X110</a>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print ''.join(soup.findAll(text=True))
# LG X110
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
<a.*<b>(.*)</b>(.*)</a>
```

$1 and $2 should be what you want, or whatever means Python has for printing captured groups.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Jens's answer. [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) is a good library you can use to actually parse this in a robust fashion. If you'd prefer something in the standard library, you can use [sax](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.html), [dom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html) or [elementree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).